# Is it possible to have mesh with NURBS editable surface

Tags: mesh, modifiers, nurbs-surface

I have a mesh that has flat top and bottom and I want to know if it's possible to edit the top and bottom just as if they were NURBS surfaces.

I have an example cube and two NURBS surfaces:
[image: cube and NURBS surfaces]

And I can achieve desired effect by converting to mesh, solidifying the two surfaces and using boolean modifiers:
[image: desired outcome]

However after doing these time consuming and irreversible steps I find that I want the surface to be curved differently.

Do I have to keep repeating these steps or is there a way to accomplish this amazing thing?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, Blender's NURBS tools are quite lacking unfortunately and the available modifiers make it hard to use in non destructive workflow. One workaround is to use mesh based surfaces instead with  *Subdivision* Modifier, something like a *Solidify* to add thickness, then use a *Boolean* non destructively

Comment: You are looking for non-destructive (procedural) workflow, so you won't go very far with Blender. Blender has some modifiers, but that's about it. Houdini is probably what you want but that is paid. You may want to look for some free CAD software like FreeCAD, NaroCAD or SolveSpace.